# How to loop over to get different array in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, angular5

```
{  
   "status":"true",
   "select":[  
      {  
         "view_":"select",
         "Type":"MARKET_WORKING",
         "Question":"WHICH BRAND COUNTER IS IT?",
         "options":[  
            {  
               "option":"USPA"
            },
            {  
               "option":"HANES"
            },
            {  
               "option":"USPA & HANES "
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "text":[  
      {  
         "view_":"select",
         "Type":"MARKET_WORKING",
         "Question":"WHAT IS THE OPENING STOCK OF INNERWEARS TOP?",
         "options":[  
            {  
               "option":"VEST"
            },
            {  
               "option":"BRA_PADDED"
            },
            {  
               "option":"BRA_NON PADDED"
            },
            {  
               "option":"CAMISOLE"
            },
            {  
               "option":"THERMAL"
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "view_":"select",
         "Type":"MARKET_WORKING",
         "Question":"WHAT IS THE OPENING STOCK OF INNERWEARS BOTTOM?",
         "options":[  
            {  
               "option":"BRIEF"
            },
            {  
               "option":"TRUNKS"
            },
            {  
               "option":"PANTIES"
            },
            {  
               "option":"THERMAL LEGGINGS"
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "view_":"select",
         "Type":"MARKET_WORKING",
         "Question":"WHAT IS THE OPENING STOCK OF COMFORTWEARS TOP?",
         "options":[  
            {  
               "option":"MEN'S T SHIRT"
            },
            {  
               "option":"MEN'S TANKS"
            },
            {  
               "option":"WOMEN'S T SHIRT"
            },
            {  
               "option":"WALL FIXTURE"
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "view_":"select",
         "Type":"MARKET_WORKING",
         "Question":"WHAT IS THE OPENING STOCK OF COMFORTWEARS BOTTOM?",
         "options":[  
            {  
               "option":"BOXER SHORTS"
            },
            {  
               "option":"MEN'S SHORTS"
            },
            {  
               "option":"MEN'S PANTS"
            },
            {  
               "option":"MEN'S SOCKS"
            },
            {  
               "option":"WOMEN'S SHORTS"
            },
            {  
               "option":"WOMEN'S PANTS"
            },
            {  
               "option":"WOMEN'S CAPRI"
            },
            {  
               "option":"WOMEN'S SOCKS"
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            },
            {  
               "option":""
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

This is `JSON` from `api`

I want to put all in loop where question and option will come respectively. For that I wrote below code

```
  if(this.user_type == 1){

        this.mwork = this.navParams.get('mwork');
        this.selectq = this.mwork.select;
        this.selecto = this.selectq[0].options;
        //this.selecto = this.selectq.options;
        this.textq = this.mwork.text;
        this.texto = this.textq[0].options;

        console.log(this.selecto);
    }
```

and below is html

```
div class="field-group" *ngFor="let mworkq of selectq">
        <div class="label-cust">{{mworkq.Question}}</div>
        <div class="field-cust">
          <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
            <option value=''>Select</option>
            <option  *ngFor="let mworkq of selecto" value="{{mworkq.option}}">{{mworkq.option}}</option>

           <!--  <option value="{{mworkq.option4}}">{{mworkq.option4}}</option> -->

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field-group" *ngFor="let mworkq of textq">
        <div class="label-cust">
              {{mworkq.Question}}
              <ion-input *ngFor="let mworkq of texto" class="{{mworkq.option}}" type="text" placeholder="{{mworkq.option}}" ></ion-input>

        </div>
```

But now what is happening only first option values are coming in all question because of `[0]`. So How can I make it dynamic to show options respective to there questions. Please help. Thank you.

For Florin I'm using below html for generating loop

```
  <div class="field-group" *ngFor="let mworkq of textq">
        <div class="label-cust">
              {{mworkq.Question}}
              <ion-input *ngFor="let mworkq of texto" class="{{mworkq.option}}" type="text" placeholder="{{mworkq.option[i]}}" ></ion-input>

        </div>
       </div>
```

From this ts

```
 for (const selectItem1 of this.mwork.text){ 
             this.textq = selectItem1.Question;       
               for (const selectItem2 of this.mwork.text){
                      this.texto = selectItem2.options;      
                    }     
        }
```

Comment: you can use `for (cont keys of Object.keys(this.mwork.select)` to iterate.

Comment: Can u please explain how to do it. becuase I'm new to backend fucntionality

Comment: `Object.keys(instanceObject)` will return every objects attribute, so you can iterate over and access to your selectq and then you can do the same thing `for (const textKeys of Object.keys(this.mwork.text)` to access all your textq

Comment: I used for Object.keys I got 0 in console

Comment: I'm writing an answer, I didn't see that your select and text are array of one item ^^

Comment: Yes..please add..M stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just change the html code to below and it works. I was taking options of api in `ts` file. It is giving me undefined. I just took `collection of first loop` from the `ts` file which is comming from api. Then for `second loop is I used value of first loop` for `collection of second loop` and then added `.options` after it for loop of options

```
<div class="field-group"  *ngFor="let mworkq of selectq">
        <div class="label-cust">{{mworkq.Question}}</div>
        <div class="field-cust">
          <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
            <option value=''>Select</option>
            <option [hidden]="mworkq.option == null || mworkq.option.length == 0" *ngFor="let mworkq of mworkq.options" value="{{mworkq.option}}">{{mworkq.option}}</option>

           <!--  <option value="{{mworkq.option4}}">{{mworkq.option4}}</option> -->

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field-group" *ngFor="let mworkq of textq">
        <div class="label-cust">
              {{mworkq.Question}}
              <ion-input [hidden]="mworkq.option == null || mworkq.option.length == 0"  *ngFor="let mworkq of mworkq.options" class="{{mworkq.option}}" type="number" placeholder="{{mworkq.option}}" ></ion-input>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably I got you wrong. But why don't you use

```
*ngFor="let option of options; index as i"
```

and afterwards

```
values[i]
```

Note: The `index as i` syntax requires Angular 5+

Comment: @SagarKodte you aren't using an index as he suggests, though.

Comment: where to use values[i]

Answer (score 1):

Your json object has three properties, `status`, `select` and `text`.

It looks like that :

```
{
 status: "",
 select: [{
   view_:"",
   Type:"",
   Question:"",
   options:[{}]
 }],
 text: [{
   {
   view_:"",
   Type:"",
   Question:"",
   options:[{}]
 }
 }]
}
```

> I want to put all in loop where question and option will come
>   respectively.

You can try this. Note that your structure looks really weird to me...and nested loop just highlight the bad structure here.

```
this.mwork = this.navParams.get('mwork');

for (const selectItem of this.mwork.select){
  console.log(selectItem.Question);
  for (const option of selectItem.options){
    console.log(option.option);
  }
}
```

**EDIT :**

Based on your question edit, you are using *ngFor directive, so you need to store your datas in an iterator. Example :

```
const mworkDatas = [];
for (const selectItem1 of this.mwork.text) {
  const question = selectItem1.Question;
  let answerOptions = [];
  for (const selectItem2 of this.mwork.text) {
   answerOptions  = selectItem2.options; 
  }
  mworkDatas.push({
    question,
    answerOptions
  });
}
```

Then in your template :

`*ngFor="let mworkData of mworkDatas"`
and you can then use :
`mworkData.question` and `mworkData.answerOptions`

Comment: Getting options undefined

Comment: I made a mistake, you can retry. But please consider thinking about your structure, if you can.

Comment: Yes I tried..still giving that error. But question is coming properly

Comment: for (const selectItem1 of this.mwork.text){ 
             this.textq = selectItem1.Question;       
               for (const selectItem2 of this.mwork.text){
                      this.texto = selectItem2.options;      
                    }     
        }  I edited your code and I'm getting both q and answer in console.but when I use it in html data is not comming

Comment: @SagarKodte Can you edit your question and show me how "you use it in hml" ?

Comment: Please see I added

Comment: cannot find name answerOptionss and answerOptions

Comment: @SagarKodte yes, sorry, you need to declare answerOptions in the parent's scope, i edited.

Comment: hey m getting same option that is last question of option in all question when I console mworkDatas

Comment: @SagarKodte : yes, in your second for loop, you should loop on `selectItem1`, not `this.mwork.text`. Or maybe add a plunkr or something so we can check directly

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it will store all options in selecto array irrespective of questions.

```
   if(this.user_type == 1){

        this.mwork = this.navParams.get('mwork');
        this.selectq = this.mwork.select;

        for(i in this.selectq)
        { 
          for(k in this.selectq[i].options)
             this.selecto.push(this.selectq[i].options[k]);
        }

        this.textq = this.mwork.text;
        this.texto = this.textq[0].options;

        console.log(this.selecto);
    }
```

Comment: What is issue in the code, please let me know. Why is it downvoted?

Comment: I believe Sagar asked for a structure that grouped the answers by question.

"But now what is happening only first option values are coming in all question because of [0]. So How can I make it dynamic to show options respective to there questions. Please help. Thank you."

The code might work, unfortunately it doesn't answer his question.

I also downvoted the question, if it makes you feel any better :P I'm not entirely sure a misunderstanding of data structures and basic for loops/how to use Angular to display them belongs on StackOverflow.

*waits for mods to come for comment :D*

Comment: @SeanAirey, The code I written has made it dynamic isn't it? this.selectq = this.mwork.select;
        for(i in this.selectq)
        { 
          for(k in this.selectq[i].options)
             this.selecto.push(this.selectq[i].options[k]);
        }

Comment: Flagged for mod attention to remove my -1 since you would have to edit answer to..... Here, add some whitespace before the loop and after the loop and I might be able to remove it before the mods see my flag :)

Comment: @SeanAirey, space added

Comment: Sorted my friend. Mods, you hate me, I'm sorry ;D